# SecurityException Requested registry access is not allowed

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, permissions, registry

I have a tool application in WPF (.NET 4.0) wich needs to access the registry and change a subkey value. But when I try to execute the app built in x86 in a Windows Server 2008 x64, I get the error "SecurityException Requested registry access is not allowed". When I execute the same application in my Windows 8 x64, the application works perfectly.

I tried to give permission for the registry keys and even change the owner, but it's no good.

The application is running as administrator and I set this value to the manifest file:

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
  <applicationRequestMinimum>
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
    <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" Unrestricted="true" />
  </applicationRequestMinimum>
</security>
```

This is the method which changes the value:

```
localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(RegistryHelper.Path64, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue);

if (localKey != null)
{
    localKey.SetValue(RegistryHelper.CsKey, CryptographyHelper.Encrypt(CryptographyHelper.DefaultKey, cs.ConnectionString));
    localKey.SetValue(RegistryHelper.ProviderKey, provider);
    localKey.Close();
}

localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(RegistryHelper.Path32, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.SetValue);

if (localKey != null)
{
    localKey.SetValue(RegistryHelper.CsKey, CryptographyHelper.Encrypt(CryptographyHelper.DefaultKey, cs.ConnectionString));
    localKey.SetValue(RegistryHelper.ProviderKey, provider);
    localKey.Close();
}
```

When I change the build to AnyCPU, the application changes the value as expected on WinServer 2008 x64, but not when built as x86. In my Windows 8 x64 it works in both x86 and x64 perfectly.
Do you guys have any clues?

Answer (score 2):

So the exception occurs when trying to access the explicitly specified 64-bit registry view location from the 32-bit application running on Windows Server 2008. This is because on Windows Server 2008 the registry is [reflected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384235(v=vs.85).aspx) resulting in the 64-bit copy of the values being inaccessible to 32-bit applications. On later versions of Windows e.g. on Win8 x64 the registry values are shared and so either view is accessible by 32-bit applications.

Although you haven't explained why the application needs to write to both physical locations on Windows Server 2008, i don't think this is going to be a problem for you because you can use an AnyCPU targeted build to update both the 32-bit and 64-bit locations because your code is explicitly opening each view in turn to do so, so i don't think you need a 32-bit build, so this question is just a curiosity right?

The answer to 
[Issue reading x64 registry keys](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92f962d6-7f5e-4e62-ac0a-b8b0c9f552a3/issue-reading-x64-registry-keys?forum=netfx64bit) might also help a little here.

Comment: We have an application that uses SqlServer, Oracle and Informix as possible databases. Because of informix, our application has to be built as x86 to work properly on envirorments x86.
This tool also has to work in x86 Windows as well and I do not want to have to generate two builds each time. I was wondering if I can keep the tool as x86 and it work for both platforms.